# A modal occupies the entire Mail app when composing a new mail

Tags: mail.app

Some annoying new feature has been added since an update I did recently. When I start to compose a new mail the compose window till appear as a modal and lock the rest of the mail app. This makes it impossible to at the same time look at other emails or use Finder to drag and drop files. Very annoying.

[image]

Does anyone know how to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature of using Mail.app in Full Screen Mode.

To disable this behaviour, use Mail.app in non-Full Screen Mode. You can do this with the menu item: **View** > **Exit Full Screen**.